# Can I use the exists function in the select part of an SQL query?

Tags: sql, sybase

I need to run a query where one of the fields returned is a yes or no if there is a row in another table matching one of the key fields in the first table.
Sounds like a job for join, except the second table is one to many and I just need to know if there are zero or a non zero number of rows in the secondary table.

I could do something like this:

```
select t1.name, t1.id, (select count(1) from t2 where t1.id=t2.id) from t1
```

but I'd like to avoid making an aggregate subquery if possible.
It was mentioned to me that I could use the exists() function, but I'm not seeing how to do that in a select field.

This is sybase 15 by the way.

Comment: Can you post some sample data and desired o/p?

Answer (score 1):

You could still do the `JOIN`, something like this:

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.id, CASE WHEN t2.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END Existst2
FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id FROM t2 GROUP BY id) t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: cute, the "group by id" is what keeps multiple rows from appearing as a result of the join? Neat trick.

Answer (score 0):

ahhh, I got it from another stackoverflow quetion...

```
case when exists (select * from t2  where t1.id = t2.id) then 1 else 0  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just writing down the syntax here:

```
if exists (select * from table1 t1 inner join table1 t2 on t1.id = t2.id )
  select * from table2
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this query ( Work with all databases )

```
select t1.name, t1.id, 'Y' as HasChild
from t1 
where exists ( select 1 from t2 where t2.id = t1.id)
UNION
select t1.name, t1.id, 'N' as HasChild
from t1 
where NOT exists ( select 1 from t2 where t2.id = t1.id)
```